# JNI Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: java-native-interface

I am getting the following error. Please advide where I may be going wrong.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Plcio.open(Ljava/lang/String;)I
at Plcio.open(Native Method)
at Plcio.main(Plcio.java:11)

I am certain that the library is present in the path specified.

**Plcio.java**

```
public class Plcio {
 private native int open(String plcName);
 static {
  //System.loadLibrary("test");
  System.load("/home/usr/plcioExampleslib/libtest.so");
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Plcio plcio = new Plcio();
  int result = plcio.open("virtual");
  System.out.println("result = " + result);
 }
}
```

**Plc.h**

```
#ifndef _PLC_H
#define _PLC_H

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<plc.h>
#include<jni.h>

typedef PLC* plcPointer;

class Plc{

public:
 Plc() { }
 Plc(const std::string &plctype, const std::vector<int> &data):_plctype(plctype),_data(data) {}

 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Plcio_open (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jstring name) ;

private:
 plcPointer _ptr;
 const std::string _plctype;
 std::vector<int> _data;
};


#endif
```

**Plc.cpp**

```
#include "Plc.h"
#include <jni.h>

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL  Plc::Java_Plcio_open (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jstring name) {

  const char *plcname = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(name, 0);
  _ptr = plc_open(const_cast<char*>(plcname));
  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(name, plcname);

  if(_ptr == NULL) {
    plc_print_error(_ptr, "plc_open\n");
    return -1;
  } else 
      cout << " open successfully " << endl; 
  return 0;    
}
```

Regards,

-H

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot use C++ instance functions as JNI functions. The runtime does not have a reference to the instance of the C++ class.

You could try declaring the `Plc::Java_Plcio_open` as `static`, that should work (but of course, brings some implications).

Comment: No, you can't simply declare Java_Plcio_open as static. Java can't find a function in a C++ class or namespace, it must be a free-standing function declared in an extern "C" block.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you are doing it very wrong. Please look up a tutoorial or some examples on JNI.

You are supposed to run javah on the class with the native method. This generates a C/C++ header file with a function declaration. It's signature of the form Java_package_name_classname_funcname. Generate the header file and then make sure your function signature is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you probably haven't implemented all headers functions.

Do the following

1 - Browse to the .so directory
2 - Do:

```
$ ld libteste.so
```

And check if there are any non implemented functions :)